# Как определить, поддерживает ли устройство Apple Pay, Samsung Pay, Android Pay?

Tags: android, ios, xcode

Подскажите как программно определить есть ли на смартфоне функция бесконтактной оплаты?

Comment: Ну с айфонами должно быть просто - если версия иОС и номер айфона выше известных величин, то поддерживает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За айфон вам [Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA) вроде написал, а я отвечу по поводу Android устройств. Как известно для того чтобы что-то оплатить в магазине вам нужен NFC модуль и программа для оплаты. Значит вы должны проверить есть ли NFC модуль на устройстве:

```
NfcManager manager = (NfcManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE);
NfcAdapter adapter = manager.getDefaultAdapter();
if (adapter != null && adapter.isEnabled()) {

    //есть модуль значит идем за покупками
}else{

   //придется снимать наличные
}
```

Так же вы должны установить платежное приложение. В документации написано:

```
To pay in stores with Google Pay, your Android phone must work with NFC (near-field communication).
```

Вот [сама](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7643995?hl=en) документация по вашему вопросу. Так же кроме проверки на наличие модуля в устройстве, можно проверить наличие программ для оплаты (Google PAY, Samsung pay):

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {

    boolean found = true;

    try {

        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        found = false;
    }

    return found;
}
```

и дальше все просто - проверяем наличие модуля и дальше проверяем наличие программы, и выводим это все пользователю.